# Need to define observation/phenomenon in order to study it, same replies to same political topics, different individuals

Tags: bias, behaviorism, cognitive

I was wondering if anyone could help me define my observation, in order to read some literature on the subject. I have some Cog. Psych. background but have never encountered this during my studies. It is a social, behavioral and a cognitive phenomenon, that I have observed reading the news and political forums. Every time N Korea is mentioned, people start talking about how hungry their nation is, and make jokes about Kim's weight. Almost every time a popular topic appears on the news regarding the subject, these kinds of posts can be seen. I can provide many examples, if necessary. It is always different individuals with the same kinds of replies/responses.

Is there anything I can read to inform myself about this phenomenon ?

EDIT: as pointed out, not all observations/phenomena need a term.  However, I do need some references to read more about it, so I am not completely lost.

Comment: Related: https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/not-all-observations-necessarily-need-a-term-in-psychology?cb=1

Comment: @Chris, good point... all I want to do is to research the phenomenon if anyone had classified it and studied it. I am not interested in whether it has a name or not, just some references.

Comment: Possibly related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/10649/7001

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's anything deeper than a [meme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme) or [stereotyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype) at play here. See https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/hungry-kim-jong-un

> On December 23rd, the "Kim Jong-Un is Hungry"[4] single topic blog launched on the microblogging site Tumblr with the tagline "He's always thinking about food. For himself… not for his people."